Spinster plans to elope with a man who might be after her money
A spinster gets involved with a man her mother does not trust and the mother won't give her blessing to the marriage as she thinks he is only after the daughter's money. 
The daughter tells him that, and suggests they should elope. He agrees and they
arrange for him to come to the house at midnight, but he does not show up. 
The mother torments her with this for years. 
The mother dies and the spinster inherits everything. Word that she is now wealthy reaches the man who let her down and he comes back to the house. The maid tells her he wants to meet her. She says come back at midnight and hears him at the door but tells the maid not to let him in.
Throughout the film she sits and works on a tapestry frame.

The year of release might help, because you're basically describing William Wyler's The Heiress (1949) with Olivia de Havilland and Montgomery Clift, but it had many other versions (which were all either based on the play The Heiress or the novel it originated from, Washington Square). Also, I'm pretty sure that it's her father that objects to her marriage in all of the versions:

In 1840's New York Catherine lives with her father, Dr. Sloper. Her mother died some years before, and Dr. Sloper still idolizers her, and never misses an opportunity to compare her daughter to her -- a comparison the daughter can never win. When Morris Townsend, a handsome but pennyless young man, comes along, and woos and wins his daughter's heart, Dr. Sloper is sure that he is after her considerable inheritance, and opposes their marriage. Dr. Sloper takes his daughter to Europe in hopes she will forget Morris, but she does not. After Catherine returns to New York, the young lovers plan to elope. Dr. Sloper threatens to disinherit his daughter. Will this dissuade Morris?

All the details fit: they plan to elope at midnight but Morris doesn't show up; her father then dies and she inherits his fortune and in the end, she finishes her embroidery when Morris comes back (at her request) at midnight and she orders the door to be bolted. Here is a list on IMDb of the other versions out there (including Washington Square from 1997 with Jennifer Jason Leigh) and here's the original trailer:




Walt, you're a STAR !

@johnkp Glad you found it. :) If the answer is correct, don't forget to click on the check mark to accept it.
